# How to search between two dates in laravel vue

Tags: javascript, mysql, laravel, vue.js, date

i have a form that has search for some data

i am able to make a search for normal fields

but i am having trouble getting date range

controller:

```
public function index() {

$query = Matter::query();

$query->when(request('search_client','search_file_ref','search_file_status','search_date_from','search_date_to'), function($query){
$query->where('client_company', 'like', '%' . request('search_client') . '%');
$query->where('file_ref', 'like', '%' . request('search_file_ref') . '%');
$query->where('status', 'like', '%' . request('search_file_status') . '%');

$query->whereBetween('created_at', ['search_date_from', 'search_date_to']);
});
return $query->orderBy('id','asc')->get();

}
```

View:

```
                <b-col md="4">
                    <form @submit.prevent="searchDateFrom">
                        <label for="">Choose File Status:</label>
                <div class="input-group">

                    <input
                        v-model="search_date_from"
                        type="date"
                        placeholder="Search File Status"
                        class="form-control"
                    />
                    <input
                        v-model="search_date_to"
                        type="date"
                        placeholder="Search File Status"
                        class="form-control"
                    />
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                            <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            </b-col>
```

...

```
data(){
    return {
        search_client: "",
        search_file_ref: "",
        search_file_status: "",
        search_date_from: "",
        search_date_to: "",
        matters:[]
    }
},
```

...

```
searchDateFrom(){
        axios.get('/api/auth/matter?search_date_from=' + this.search_date_from + 'search_date_to=' + this.search_date_to)
        .then(response => this.matters = response.data)

    },
```

so when i try to do this in controller:

```
$query->whereBetween('created_at', ['2022-06-01', '2022-06-07']);
```

i'm getting the data and correct range

but when i add the request to it like this:

```
$query->whereBetween('created_at', ['search_date_from', 'search_date_to']);
```

i stop getting data from API and nothing shows

Model:

```
{
use HasFactory;
protected $fillable = [
    'matter_type','client_company','description','file_group',
    'control_account','pic','lawyer','task_assign','task_recipient',
    'file_ref','remark','purchaser_1','purchaser_2','status'
];
protected $casts = [
'created_at' => 'datetime:m / d / Y',
];
}
```

am i doing anything wrong with the request?

i'm able to get data and search other fields (other than date)

and trying to achieve search field so the user is able to set two dates and get the results between this range

Comment: What about converting a dates object in to a date string and do search ? I think this will be a easiest way to do.

Comment: You are fetching you request parameter wrong, do this `$query->whereBetween('created_at', [request('search_date_from'), request('search_date_to')]);` instead of `$query->whereBetween('created_at', ['search_date_from', 'search_date_to']);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is correct but you made a small mistake as you forget to wrap your date params in the `request` helper. Instead of passing dates from request, you were passing the strings literals `search_date_from` and `search_date_to` to the `whereBetween` statement.

Your code

```
$query->whereBetween('created_at', ['search_date_from', 'search_date_to']);
```

Corrected code

```
$query->whereBetween('created_at', [request('search_date_from'), request('search_date_to')]);
```

**Kindly see the bellow corrected code.**

```
public function index() {

        $query = Matter::query();

        $query->when(request('search_client','search_file_ref','search_file_status','search_date_from','search_date_to'), function($query){
            $query->where('client_company', 'like', '%' . request('search_client') . '%');
            $query->where('file_ref', 'like', '%' . request('search_file_ref') . '%');
            $query->where('status', 'like', '%' . request('search_file_status') . '%');

            $query->whereBetween('created_at', [request('search_date_from'), request('search_date_to')]);
        });
        return $query->orderBy('id','asc')->get();

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all you have written your variables as string here. `$query->whereBetween('created_at', ['search_date_from', 'search_date_to']);`

You can write like this `$query->whereBetween('created_at', [$search_date_from, $search_date_to]);`

I prefer writing like this one:  `$query->whereBetween(DB::raw("DATE('created_at')"), array($from, $to));`

Comment: Why you have suggested using a raw query ?

Comment: Actually I use `DB::raw("DATE()")` when the column is date. else I directly write column name. I think `DB::raw("DATE()")` would effect in performance looking for a Date column. `$isDate ? $query->whereBetween(DB::raw("DATE($key)"), array($from, $to)) : $query->whereBetween($key, array($from, $to));`

Comment: Your search query is like static. I mean that now you are writing your search query in every Controller. while you can make a helper function which gets your ClassName:: with list of columns which you are searching for.